# How to invoke discord function inside the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm new to discord py and asyncio. I want the bot to run the function five times inside the loop.

```
from discord.ext import commands
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!')
a=0
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot online')
@Bot.command()
async def msg(ctx):
   global a
   a=a+1
   await ctx.author.send(a)

for i in range(5):
   msg()
Bot.run('token')
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work without manual entering the command in the channel (!msg). Moreover, it doesn't do it in a loop. How to invoke discord function as standard python function?

Answer (score 3):

You are using an async command without await

```py
for _ in range(5):
    await msg()
```

But...
I highly dout it would work at all because of the way you want to use the msg function
better solution is

```py
a = 0
async def send_message_and_increment(ctx):
    global a
    a += 1
    await ctx.send(a) # send to text_channel the user was in
    await ctx.author.send(a) # send to the user (DM) that invoke the command 

@Bot.command()
async def msg(ctx):
   global a

    for _ in range(5):
        await send_message_and_increment(ctx)
```

Comment: It still need to go to discord and write !msg in channel. Is there a way to just print messages without command? I just need to print some data that comes from another process every 2 minutes in channel.

Comment: I've found out that i can use webhooks instead. Anyway thank you!